# Angular ignores given HttpHeaders for post request

Tags: angular, rest, http

I am using json-server and want to request data as post method with request body. It works with Postman but not with Angular. In Angular is the content type allways text/plain no matter what i am trying. What i am missing?

```
getProjects(request: ProjectRequest): Observable<Project[]> {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('accessToken')!);

const body = JSON.stringify(request);

return this.http.post<Project[]>(this.apiGetProjects, body, { headers: headers });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to stringify the body. Just do this

```
this.http.post<Project[]>(this.apiGetProjects, request, { headers: headers });
```

## OffTopic

1. Don't set the `content-type` header. Angular will do it for you.
2. Don't set the `authorization` header here. Just use a `HttpInterceptor`. [Look at this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8).